# Django AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'init'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, vagrant

I'm new to Django. I'm using version 1.11.6 in a vagrant box with ubuntu

I added an ImageField to one of my models. Everything was working fine. Today (after rebooting) the same code throws this error (whenever I call manage.py):

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import (
... more files in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/..
    from django.core import validators
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/validators.py", line 507, in <module>
    allowed_extensions=get_available_image_extensions(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/validators.py", line 502, in get_available_image_extensions
    Image.init()
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'init'
```

The exception thrown in the validators.py from django

```
def get_available_image_extensions():
    try:
        from PIL import Image
    except ImportError:
        return []
    else:
        Image.init()
        return [ext.lower()[1:] for ext in Image.EXTENSION.keys()]
```

I installed Pillow as the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) says

```
sudo pip3 install Pillow
```

In the python3 console, I can import Image from PIL correctly, but it doesn't have the init() method. What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: In the shell, what is the output of `dir(Image)` after importing `Image` from `PIL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this isn't the best answer, but I uninstalled pillow, reinstalled it again, erase everything in the `__pycache__` folder and now it works.